# Oxford staking mechanics

Tags: baking, staking, staking-balance

I'd like to get clarification on how staking works now in relation to deactivating a baker.

Previous to Oxford activating, a baker would get their stake spendable/unfrozen immediately on the cycle after the baker's rights ended.

Now it looks like the baker has to wait for rights to run out and then subsequently wait for 7 cycles for the unstaked balance to become spendable.

Can someone run through these changes or provide the compare/contrast?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, since Oxford2 activated, the staking mechanics have changed, as a necessary migration step in order to further change and improve in Paris with Adaptive Issuance (AI).

We encountered 2 scenarios:

(1) Baker deactivated since Oxford went into effect (this is the way going forward, before Paris is activated /w AI).

Here are the 2 tezbake/Octez commands needed to release the baker's stake:

```
tezbake signer client set deposits limit for baker to 0
tezbake signer client finalize unstake for baker
```

After setting deposits limit to 0, which is now mandatory to deactivate, the baker has to use the finalize unstake operation to receive stake back, after the stake is no longer slashable (~7 cycles).

(2) The baker deactivated before Oxford2 went into effect.

The baker has to reactivate, then on the following cycle deactivate by setting deposits limit to 0. After waiting the additional 7 cycles like above, and executing the finalize unstake command, the baker should get their stake back.

---

This change could have used more focus, especially since changing the fundamental way the delegate logistics work is not something that happens frequently.

Answer (score 1):

For delegates deactivated in Oxford, the staked funds of delegates are automatically unstaked. However, as the delegate is deactivated, the autostaking will not automatically finalize the unstaked funds. One has to use 7 cycles later the manual finalize operation described here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/paris/adaptive_issuance.html#staked-funds-management.

For the few bakers that have been deactivated a few cycles **before** Oxford, the automatic unstaking did not occur, and they will have staked funds that cannot be manually unstaked. To recover these funds, they need to:

1. Reactivate themselves with the set_delegate operation.
2. Set their deposit limit to 0 (end-of-cycle autostaking will then unstake the funds).
3. Wait 7 cycles for the funds to be finalizable.
4. Perform a manual finalization.

Comment: I had this answer prepared, that roughly says the same as Baking Benjamins did, but put in other words, so I thought it was worth publishing it anyway.